# Previous shell setting prevents console2 from starting

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, console2

Few months ago, I was using Cygwin and [Console](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) on windows 7  and created a bash session in Console. Now that I uninstalled Cygwin, Console complains with:

```
Unable to start a C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe --login -i!
```

I sarched through the registry but couldn't find the remains of Console. How can I reset/get rid of this error?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Console stores profiles at:

> C:\Users\ [USER] \AppData\Roaming\ [CONSOLE TAB NAME] \console.xml

Try Replacing it with original one located in Installation Directory,

> C:\Program Files\Console2\console.xml

Path might be different depending on where you have installed it.

Comment: And the problem data is inbetween <console> tags. Thank you. Yhat was what I was looking for.

Comment: Happened to me when upgrading GIT but I wasn't getting any errors, only a window that closes after a fraction of a second.  Git moved from `Program Files (x86)` to just `Program Files`.  I just had to change the shell command in the console tag, I think it was just exiting and I wasn't getting errors because it has to use `cmd.exe /c` which was able to be found, just the argument was pointing to the wrong folder for my default shell.

Answer (score 0):

Do a registry cleanup with a software like Ccleaner, they are mutch better than you at finding orphaned keys. Otherwise uninstall console, restart the pc and reinstall it.

Comment: Even Ccleaner didn't help, I tried every way to remove the remnants from the registry but at the end, had to completely wipe the registry using the windows rescue partition. To note, even selecting the option to backup home directory didn't help.